# How to select an <option> within a dropdown by value and assign the "selected" attribute to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a dropdown list (`<select>`), at some point I need to find the option with a given value and assign the `selected` attribute to it.

e.g.:

```
<select id="font-size">
    <option value="12">12px</option>
    <option value="13">13px</option>
    <option value="14">14px</option>
</select>
```

In the example above, how would I add the "selected='selected'" attribute to the `option` with the value 14?

Comment: do you want this when the user selects the option?

Comment: No, not then. This is for showing to the user which is their current font size, at any given moment. So the list would have already been rendered at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it:

```
$('#font-size').val(14);
```

NB: this sets the `selected` *property* on the required `<option>` element - the *attribute* represents the *initital* value of the dropdown when the page is first loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to set the initial value when the page is loaded then use,

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#font-size').val(14);
   });
```

or else if you want it the value of which user has selected after the loading use this,

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#font-size').change(function() {
       alert($(this).val());
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("font-size").value = "14";
```